# How to register a Spring batch in Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I don't understand how to register an app. I followed a lot of guides and they use this example to explain it:

`dataflow:>app register --name fileIngest --type task --uri file:///path/to/target/ingest-X.X.X.jar`

My jar is in "C:\Temp" but if i set the uri: file:///Temp/myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
i have this error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /Temp/myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar must exist`

Can someone explain me how to run a local batch with Spring Cloud Data Flow in local?

Comment: i installed SCDF with docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood how to do it. In docker-compose.yml i set the path in skipper-server and dataflow-server like this:

```
image: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:${DATAFLOW_VERSION:?DATAFLOW_VERSION is not set!} 
container_name: dataflow-server 
volumes: - 'C:/Temp:/root/apps'

"Then the right way to register the app is: "
app register --name 'mybatch' --type task --uri file:///root/apps/myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

What you tried is intended to be used in the Unix box, but for Windows, you'd have to point to the file with a different namespace pattern.

Perhaps try this:

> app register --name fileIngest --type task --uri file:/C:/Temp/myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Command failed org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: Existing default application [file:///root/apps/myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar] can only differ by a version but is [file:/C:/Temp/myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar]

Comment: I understood how to do it. In docker-compose.yml i set the path in skipper-server and dataflow-server like this:
dataflow-server:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:${DATAFLOW_VERSION:?DATAFLOW_VERSION is not set!}
    container_name: dataflow-server
    volumes:
      - 'C:/Temp:/root/apps'

Then the right way to register the app is:
app register --name 'mybatch' --type task --uri file:///root/apps/myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar